# How to extract/decode expiration time from externally issued Json Web Token

Tags: web-services, rest, groovy, jwt

so I am working with a 3rd party RESTful webservice where I have to authenticated myself by requesting a JWT and provide it to any further requests.
I do that by just posting my username and password and recieve a token for this. I neither know the secret used to create the token nor anything else besides username and password.

Now, I would like to check the expiration time of the JWT before I either reuse it for subsequent webservice requests or just renew it. I know i could just used it and catch some kind of expiration exception but I would prefer not to.

I tried to follow this tutorial: [https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java]

but get stuck at the point where I have to provide signing key.

How would I do that since I do not have the secret used to encode it.

Bye the way: I am working with groovy and [wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to take the body of the token, and decode it.

The private key isn't used to encrypt the body of a JWT, it's just used to generate the signature...

So, in Groovy you can just do:

```
// A JWT from the link you gave above
String key = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdHJ1c3R5YXBwLmNvbS8iLCJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsInN1YiI6InVzZXJzLzg5ODM0NjIiLCJzY29wZSI6InNlbGYgYXBpL2J1eSJ9.43DXvhrwMGeLLlP4P4izjgsBB2yrpo82oiUPhADakLs'

// Just the body (middle section)
String body = key.split(/\./)[1]

// Un base64 it (using the Java 8 Base64 class)
String unencoded = new String(Base64.decoder.decode(body), 'UTF-8')

// Parse the json into a map
Map data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(unencoded)

// Get the expiry
long exp = data.exp

assert exp == 1300819380
```

Of course, there's nothing to say that the body of the token has to contain any form of expiry time for you to look at...  It could just be an internal ID

Comment: I am going to try that as soon as I am back from my vacation. In case there is no expiration info, how would you go about dealing with this?

Comment: If they don't tell you when it expires, you'll have to catch the expiry exception, revalidate, and retry

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the cipher used to encode it nor want to crack their cipher then you can't decode any information from the token. There is nothing like 'standard information that must be encoded in token', there's no need to the token that it should contain any ciphered information at all, it could be just an randomly generated UUID stored on their side in DB, so in that case you can't decode it at all.

Comment: But you are right that the token need not have any information like an expiry time

Comment: @tim_yates So in your opinion base64 encoding isn't a form of ciphering?

Comment: Yeah, in the same way a Caesar cipher is.  But you said _"If you don't know the cipher..."_  But of course you know the _"cipher"_ ... It's Base64 encoded, just like it says in [Section 3 of the Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-3)

Comment: My point is that your first sentence is not relevant in this case...  With other systems maybe, but not with JWT where the encryption is used for validating the signature, not encrypting the message

Comment: from where do you know that He deal with Json Web Token and not other mechanism?

Comment: He mentions JWT twice in the question, once in the title and tagged the question as JWT as well...

Comment: He mentioned Java Web Token and not Json Web Token

Comment: As Java Web Token isn't a thing (he mentions that once in the title, and JWT everywhere else), I assumed they'd made a mistake

Comment: Indeed I had some kind of brain fart and wrote Java Web token by accident. Ofc o meant Jason Web token